# Search Filter With Custom Taxonomy and Custom Fields : How do I handle it via plugin?

Tags: wp-query, ajax, templates

I'm looking for suggestions on where exactly to put my 'results display' code. I am aware that templates are the way to handle how wordpress outputs stuff; but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to use templates in following situation I'm currently dealing with.

Here's an overall view of what I'm doing:-

```
+----------------------------------------+
| My Post Filter Plugin: Allows          |
| filtering of posts using custom        |
| taxonomies and post meta fields        |
|                                        |
+-+--------------------------------------+
  |
  |        +--------------------------------+
  |        | filter_form.php (Has html code |
  |        | for displaying filter fields.  |
 ++--------+                                |
           +-+------------------------------+
             |
             | Triggers AJAX Request on 'Submit'.
             | Handled by admin-ajax.php using
             | wp_ajax_process_search
             |
             v
 +-----------+------------------------------+
 | function process_search() {              |
 | reads $_POST data and gets results       |
 | using WP_QUERY (CODE BELOW)              |
 |                                          |
 +------------------------------------------+
```

Now, this process_search() function looks like this:

```
process_search() {
...
fetches all $_POST data from the filter_form and builds $prepare_args to be passed to WP_QUERY
---

$query_result = new WP_Query( $prepare_args );
```

wp_send_json_success($results);
    }

### PROBLEM

My $query_result indeed gets desired results; which indicates that my code works. Now, since process_search() resides inside plugin; I am really not sure how to render the output.

### Option 1:

Send the $results back ajax and have jQuery append them to desired DIV. But this totally breaks pagination. I do not want complex logic for handling pagination.

### Option 2:

Make use of the WordPress' templates (archive.php or search.php) to render the results and have pagination work automatically. But then, how do I send the output to these templates?

Also, I'm not very keen on using AJAX. What'd be the right way to achieve desired output without leaving the boundaries of plugin and not having to add a theme just to handle the output?

I apologize for long question. I've already been scratching my head for almost 3 days on this. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Templates output results from the main query, so if you want your results to render as an archive normally does, then your code should modify the main query rather than create a new one.

Comment: I see. Are you suggesting the use of pre_get_posts or is there any other approach? Also, how do I render the templates from within my plugin code?